# password_verify won't work after storing in database

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I have been searching and reading for about 50 posts about my problem, but still can't figure out my problem, so I am here.

Problem: `password_verify()` returns false even if password is correct.

This is how I store password into db(When register and edit profile)

```
$hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

And my latest `password_verify()` (I have tried many examples, no one works and now I'm sitting here with still not working code)

```
public function doLogin($username,$password){
    try{

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username=:username");
        $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (password_verify($password, $userRow['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['id'];
            $_SESSION["result"]='You have succesfully logged in your profile!';
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

My database field is 25 characters long. What is wrong here?

Comment: Is the database query retrieving the user record? What should your code do if there is no matching user record? Is the password hash being returned by the database query correct? Is the password hash the correct length? Have you don't anything to $password before calling this function (like escaping it) or did you do anything to the entered password in registration or editing?

Comment: How long is the `password` column? How do you insert the password?

Comment: Seems like you escaped string the password, thus changing it's value. And length of the password column should be at least 60

Comment: @Qirel 25 symbols

Comment: @Akintunde Sorry, I'm newbie in this and do not really understand, what do you mean.

Comment: @Crelix - password field in the database should be at least 60 characters, and 255 is recomended... so how long is your password column on the users table?

Comment: @MarkBaker Okay, I will change that right now. And amm... 25 symbols?

Comment: Your `password` column need a minimum length of 60, recommended is 255. Any passwords you already have, needs to be updated - as they have their lengths turnicated now.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks man. Simply changed to 255 and it works now. I was desperated with this simple problem.. Please make it as answer, so I can check it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the manual for `password_hash()`

> [...] Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)

That means that `password_verify()` will silently fail if you have a column that has length of 59 or less. Because MySQL will truncate the the hashed string when you insert the hashed password without saying anything.

The solution is to set your `password` column to length of 60 or higher - the manual suggests setting it to 255, so just do that.

Any passwords already stored won't have their hashes fixed, so they need to be updated or re-inserted.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php